# How to allow external user to access SharePoint 2016 intranet?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

We have SharePoint 2016 on-premise intranet in our company and now we need to give access to external users having their own domain and network. What is the best way to give access for them apart from VPN?

1.DNS is not accessible via internet

2.We have already setup FBA

3.Users are present in Oracle IDM

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you're also using Active Directory, I think you should consider looking into [Azure Proxy Services](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy).

If you're using Active Directory and can add the external users that way, this should be a good service. Right now we use the proxy service, and can access our http intranet by an https site under the same url. (ie http://myIntranet/ was accessible via https://myIntranet/).

I'm not entirely certain on the setup behind the scenes, but I hope this leads you into the right direction.

Comment: Thanks much for the response KGlasier, we are using AD however external users are in Oracle IDM, does Azure Proxy services support this scenario?